# Why are user's facebook id's changing in ios?

Tags: ios, facebook

I am new to integrating facebook. So far I have the login implemented. I have been saving the users id in our database as a way to recognize them when they login.  However I noticed today that the id changed.  If the id changes, what can I use to identify the facebook users?

Here is the code I am using, g_fb_id is the id that is passed to our servers.

```
// This method will handle ALL the session state changes in the app
- (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session state:(FBSessionState) state error:(NSError *)error
{
    // If the session was opened successfully
    if (!error && state == FBSessionStateOpen){
        NSLog(@"Session opened");

        // get facebook ID
        [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user, NSError *error) {
            if (! error) {
                g_fb_id = [user objectForKey:@"id"];
                g_user.birthday=user.birthday;
                g_user.fb_page=[user objectForKey:@"link"];
                g_user.first_name=user.first_name;
                g_user.last_name=user.last_name;
                g_user.email=[user objectForKey:@"email"];
                g_user.gender=[user objectForKey:@"gender"];



                [self fbLoggedIn];
            } else {
                [self fbLoginFailed:@"Login failed !!!"];
            }
        }];
    } else if (state == FBSessionStateClosed || state == FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed){
        // If the session is closed
    } else {
        // handle errors
        // Clear this token
        [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
        [self fbLoginFailed:@"Login failed !!!"];
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you notice the id changing? Do you store ids somewhere, and if so, where and how?

Comment: What do you mean by the id is changed? Like you actually print out the id and compared the corresponding one in your database?

Comment: Yes, I store them in the database and on the phone.  So next time a user logs in, if they match, I auto log them in.  Was working well until the id changed for the user and no longer matched my database.